# How to change Grid Content?

Tags: wpf

I am asking for a programming approach.

This is my problem:

I have a WPF window, with a ComboBox at the top.

When user select the item in combobox, depends on the selection, the Grid below it will show a corresponding element, for example: if use choose Display from combobox, then the element in Grid will change to a ListView; and when user choose Add from combobox, the element in Grid will change to a form(textboxes).

Should I create several Grid, collapse them, and show them only when user make selection? Or any other more brilliant ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want a grid? Is grid necessary? Can't it be a panel? You might dynamically render the content of the panel/groupbox.

Comment: Not necessary a grid, any control that can render my content will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two ways:

You add one panel containing the controls required for each of the items in the combobox. You can hide all of them and on `SelectedIndexChanged`, you can show the appropriate panel. This will need more memory, but the implementation is simpler.

The other way will be to have a single panel and render the controls in run time on `SelectedIndexChanged`. This will need less memory, but will be complex to implement. Also rendering on run time might need some additional time (so the throughput).

Comment: I used the first option, because I want to preserve the data and objects from recreate when user change selected index. Since the menu that I created is not the core menu, so performance issue is not that crucial. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Put a `UserControl` in the cell, and set its `Content` according to the control selected in the ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is place a Panel(Like `Grid`, `DockPanel`) below the combobox and based on it's selection, dynamically add/remove controls in the panel.

For ex: If the user selects Display, then, remove all the child elements of the `Panel` and add a `GridView`.If Add is selected, remove all child elements and add a `TextBox`.

After adding, attach an event handler in code behind to perform the action you would want to perform.